# How to use MS Access connection string with Oracle authentication

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

With C# and ADO.NET, I am trying to automate the reports generation which currently run as macros in MS Access database. When you execute the macro in Access, it prompts you to enter Oracle credentials and then create reports in excel sheets.

My code is running fine and I am able to create these reports but, when my code executes, it prompts for Oracle credentials.

This new application will run everyday during the night time and will not have a user present to input Oracle credentials.

I tried creating two separate connection strings and open both connections at the same time, but of course it didn't work. Then I tried creating single connection string with Oracle user id and password as shown below, but it also failed.

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ProjectDocs\CE_REPORTS.accdb;User ID=JOHNDOE;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*********"/>
```

This is the first time I am dealing with Access database which is not using its own authentication  feature. Please let me know how I can solve this.

Thank you

Comment: It may be worth checking your connection string. This may be helpful: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: You post a connection string to Access, but wish to open a connection to Oracle db. It doesn't make sense. It is Access that should open a connection to Oracle; include code in Access to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have your .net part, and it can of course create its own connection to Oracle (and it should).

This does beg the question as to why .net is being introduced here? If you were just reading/writing Access data tables from .net, then fine. but you are ALSO then using Access reports. (So it begs the question what advantages using .net here has at all?).

Regardless, if you launch Access, use the linked table manager, and check this box during the link process:

[image]

As a result, when you create a COM object (automation copy) from .net, then the launch of Access and use of those linked tables SHOULD NOT occur.

Use the Access UI to create a linked table to Oracle. But, remember Access has a complex cache system. If you execute a logon from Access to Oracle? Then the linked tables do NOT need to include Userid/password. This means in effect you can link the tables from Access (but without user/password), and then execute a one time logon from Access (VBA code). This logon routine could also be called by your .net automaton instance of Access you are using.

But, if you do and have the correct linked table setup in access, and you checked the above "remember" password during that link process, then no prompts to logon to Oracle should exist.